# Does CQL3 client support native protocol?

Tags: cassandra

Is it possible to use the CQL3 java client (the one using execute_prepared_cql3_query etc)
with the native protocol in 2.0?
Or is the Datastax java client the only one that supports the native protocol?
Is there a performance benefit in using the native protocol especially when inserting 1MB blobs?
I have existing applications that are using the CQL3 client, hence would prefer not to port unless the performance benefit is large.

Comment: What is the other driver are you referring to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DataStax Java Driver for Apache Cassandra (https://github.com/datastax/java-driver) is the only Java Driver to support the CQL Native Protocol so far.

To clarify details about this new protocol: the CQL Native Protocol v1 has been introduced in Cassandra 1.2 and then enhanced as CQL Native Protocol v2 in Cassandra 2.0. While the Thrift interface will remain supported for a while in upcoming versions of Cassandra, you can expect some features to be only available with the CQL Native Protocol in the future, which is already the case with Automatic Paging in Cassandra 2.0 (see http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/client-side-improvements-in-cassandra-2-0).

On the performance side, there's still no clear benchmark to compare efficiency of Thrift vs. CQL Native Protocol publicly available. That's something we wish to see soon. Keep in mind though that there's no one size fits all answer to this performance question as it will heavily depends on the use case and workload being considered. That's why I would definitely advice you to run your own performance tests and see how you can improve the efficiency of your application. I would just note that for the 1MB blob case that you've mentioned, I don't expect much difference as the payload will be much bigger than the protocol overhead here.

As a consequence I wouldn't say that it's urgent for you to upgrade to a driver supporting the CQL Native Protocol, but that's something that you should start to experiment as most of the investments will happen there in the years to come.